# Cannot use date.parse on firefox. It works on Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

I'm not experienced with jQuery, so I stacked to a problem.
The problem is that in Chrome my code works fine, but in Firefox it doesn't.
It seems that the date.parse command is not working because "tsv" data is fine but "date" data is not.

The codes is below. If anyone can help me please let me know...

```
jQuery.get('data.php', null, function(tsv) {
                var lines = [];
                traffic = [];
                try {
                    // split the data return into lines and parse them
                    tsv = tsv.split(/\n/g);
                    jQuery.each(tsv, function(i, line) {
                        line = line.split(/\t/);
                    var date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');
                        traffic.push([
                            date,
                            parseFloat(line[1].replace(',', ' '), 10)
                        ]);
                    }) ;
                } catch (e) {  }
                options.series[0].data = traffic;
                chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);

    // alert(tsv);
     // alert(traffic);
   //    alert(date);
            }) ;
```

Comment: What is format of date string in line[0]?

Comment: I have corrected it to "var date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC');"

Comment: I think we need to know what `line[0]` evaluates to in `date = Date.parse(line[0] +' UTC')`. Can you `console.log()` this value and add to your question?

Comment: I  dont know how to use console.log();


The date data is NaN and tsv data=
2013-04-06 22:46:08 24.81,2013-04-06 22:47:07 24.75,2013-04-06 22:48:06 24.69,2013-04-06 22:49:06 24.63,2013-04-06 22:50:06 24.63,2013-04-06 22:51:06 24.63,2013-04-06 22:52:06

Answer (score 5):

Firefox does not support parsing dates in the format 2013-04-06 22:46:08.

You can use the [date.js](http://www.datejs.com/) library to get support for this format.

If you don't want to use date.js then the function below will parse the date from yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss format to UTC.

```
function parseDateUTC(input) {
    var reg = /^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2}) (\d{2}):(\d{2}):(\d{2})$/;
    var parts = reg.exec(input);
    return parts ? (new Date(Date.UTC(parts[1], parts[2] -1, parts[3], parts[4], parts[5],parts[6]))) : null
}
```

Then you just have to change your code to

```
var date = parseDateUTC(line[0]);
```

Comment: can you just give me an example that I could use?
I just need it to be working to either firefox or chrome.
I have saved date.js to the same folder as index.php. How to replace date.parse with date.js???

Comment: If you include the date.js library on your page you won't need to make any changes to your js. To include the date.js file on index.php just add '<script type="text/javascript" src="date.js">' to the html (if date.js is in the same folder as index.php)

Comment: Date.js should work but without seeing your whole page I can't debug the problem. Instead of using date.js I have edited my answer to include a function that will parse the date. It's a lot less flexible than the date.js function, but it does the job.

Comment: Thanks a lot my friend!!!!
Works like a charm now!!!  
Does it matter where I add the date code for faster browsing???

Comment: Great. Performance wise it doesn't matter where you add the code. Don't forget to accept the answer if it worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

`date.js` is no longer updated, in fact, the website is down for me. I have read that the best replacement for it is [MomentJS](http://momentjs.com/). as per [parsing](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/)

```
moment().format('1995-02-23 12:14:16', 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I ended up including date.js (include this as a script and it will overwrite the date.parse() function).

Yet, to make it work in HighStocks I needed to convert the result into milliseconds. If dateString contains a Date in one of the formats date.js can convert, then

```
dateString= Date.parse(dateString);
```

works only in Chrome, but

```
dateString= Date.parse(dateString).getTime();
```

converts any of the results browsers offer into milliseconds and so far it works for me...